# Discrepancy in I2C behaviour of two microcontrollers EFR32MG21A020F1024IM32 and MCP39F521

Tags: i2c

I am using EFR32MG21A020F1024IM32 to communicate with the energy meter (MCP39F521) using I2C protocol to read the data from the energy meter registers. I2C is used in standard mode and configuring the i2c as gpioModeWiredAnd having a pullup resistance of 2.2k ohm.
First I am writing the read command packet {0xA5, 0x08, 0x41, 0x00, 0x02, 0x4E, 0x20, 0x5E} to the slave address. The 7 bit slave address is 0x74.
At first when writing the read command packet and all the bits are getting acknowledged along with the start and stop conditions.
While receiving I gave the slave address as ((0x74 << 1) | 0x01). But we are not getting any response and the address itself is not getting acknowledged.

The same board has a STM32L412CBT6P chip on the same line. when using this board to communicate with MCP39F521 i am getting the proper responses and the register readings.

PFA the image captured while probing the i2c lines while communicating using EFR32MG21A020F1024IM32.[image]
A
ny help or suggestion regarding this would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get yourself a cheapy logic analyser. Decoding I2C from your scope pic is painful. Have you checked to see if the I2C code expects a 7 or 8 bit address? This is a common cause of confusion.

Comment: Do you expect the chip to be able to respond immediately after it has received a command? If yes, check that it is ready, compare with timing of the transmissions that work.

Comment: @Justme i tried giving a delay between writing and reading but that also gave the same response

Comment: @Kartman It expects a 7 bit slave address only.